# Включить альтернативную цветовую схему Windows 10

Tags: windows, accessibility

Имеется необходимость программно включить альтернативную цветовую схему в windows 10. Как можно это сделать? Пока что поиски ничего не дали, буду благодарен любой помощи. Заранее спасибо.

UPD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что ты имеешь в виду под "альтернативной цветовой схемой"? Попробуй, что ли, на скрине в пейнте порисовать. Где и какие цвета ты хочешь изменить?

Comment: @Gh0sTG0, добавил скрины к вопросу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Программно переключить фильтры без перезагрузки/деавторизации не удалось, поэтому решил проблему с помощью [Magnification.dll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/magapi/magapi-intro). Помимо этого, наткнулся на [репозиторий](https://github.com/mlaily/NegativeScreen), в котором реализованы матрицы некоторых цветовых фильтров. Также,
[гайд](https://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide/) по этим матрицам.